# Error by using both tikz external and algpseudocodex

Tags: tikz-pgf, algpseudocode, external

In my latex file, I am using `tikz` with the `external` option to avoid recompilation, and I am using `algpseudocodex` for pseudocode, but it seems like some commands in the `algorithmic` environment are recognized as PGF commands and errors are raised.

Here is a minimum code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algpseudocodex}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=tikz/]

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw=red, fill=yellow] {hello};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{algorithm}[hbt!]
    \label{alg:my-algorithm}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \Require $n$
        \Ensure $s$
        \For{$i \gets 1$ to $n$}
            \State $s \gets s + i$
        \EndFor
        \State \Return $s$
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Part of the error message is:

```
Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.32         \State
                    \Return $s$
Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.32         \State
                    \Return $s$
Package pgf Error: No shape named `algpx@indentStart-0' is known.

See the pgf package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.32         \State
                    \Return $s$
Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \algpx 
                  @indStartX ,\algpx @indEndY 
l.32         \State
                    \Return $s$
```

But if I don't use tikz's external feature, i.e., `\usetikzlibrary{external}` and `\tikzexternalize[prefix=tikz/]` are commented, there is no error.
How should I insert pseudocode and avoid recompiling unmodified tikz figures?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `algopseudocodex` package uses TikZ internally.
The easiest solution would be to disable the externalization for the `algorithmic` environment by doing

```
\AddToHook{env/algorithmic/begin}{\tikzexternaldisable}
```

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algpseudocodex}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=tikz/]
\AddToHook{env/algorithmic/begin}{\tikzexternaldisable}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw=red, fill=yellow] {hello};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{algorithm}[hbt!]
    \label{alg:my-algorithm}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \Require $n$
        \Ensure $s$
        \For{$i \gets 1$ to $n$}
            \State $s \gets s + i$
        \EndFor
        \State \Return $s$
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! This simple solution works. That is awesome!